# Application crashes in asynctask(server api call) after proguard obfuscation

Tags: android, proguard

After proguard enabled app is crashing when i call Asynctask(server api call) but it's not crashing if proguard is disabled.and in my application am using third party api's Universalimageloader and Multipartentity (Httpmime,httpcore,httpclient)for sending image to server but these asynctask work is next to crashed asynctask.

**Log:**

```
01-13 11:58:36.069: E/dalvikvm(6501): Could not find class 'javax.naming.ldap.LdapName', referenced from method a.a.a.e.d.a.b
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246): Process: com.myapp.package, PID: 22246
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: a/a/a/e/d/a
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at a.a.a.e.d.f.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at a.a.a.h.c.m.a(Unknown Source)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at a.a.a.h.b.a.d(Unknown Source)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at a.a.a.h.b.a.r(Unknown Source)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at a.a.a.h.b.a.c(Unknown Source)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at a.a.a.h.b.a.a(Unknown Source)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at a.a.a.h.b.i.a(Unknown Source)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at a.a.a.h.b.i.b(Unknown Source)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at a.a.a.h.b.i.a(Unknown Source)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at com.myapp.package.aw.a(Unknown Source)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at com.myapp.package.t.a(Unknown Source)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at com.myapp.package.t.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-12 18:05:15.247: E/AndroidRuntime(22246):    ... 4 more
```

Inproguardproject.txt

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses

-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
-dontwarn javax.naming.**
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**

-dontpreverify
-libraryjars libs/httpmime-4.3.5.jar
-libraryjars libs/httpclient-4.3.5.jar
-libraryjars libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field
```

In Asyntask am making a call to the server

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
            CONNECTION_ESTABLISH_TIME_OUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters,
            DATA_WAIT_TIME_OUT);
    mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    HttpResponse mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);
    statusCode = mHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    mEntity = mHttpResponse.getEntity();
    String strjson = EntityUtils.toString(mEntity);
    parsingJson(strjson);
    return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Crash happens because of the proguard changed the http package class files.

```
-keep class org.apache.http.** {
    *;
}
```

Comment: I've had the same issue, and that was happening in Obfuscated Code only. So keeping the whole org.apache package solved it.